# Aligning text to leading inside NavigationLink not working in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, alignment

Tried to align text to `leading` of a view in SwiftUI within `NavigationLink` is not working, but if I didn't used `NavigationLink` it's working fine.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                Text("fsdf")
            } label: {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("sdfsdlfjskfjsd sdflkjsdf sf sljdflsdkf asfjslkdfj sdfjlskfj sdfjldksfj asdfvfvf fvfvf fvfvl,v vfvl")

                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,alignment:.leading)
                }
                .frame(width: 300,height: 100)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .overlay {
                    // ...
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output now:
[image]

I need the output as below :
[image]

My ultimate goal is while clicking on the entire view I need to navigate to next view.

Answer (score 2):

Use Text modifier `.multilineTextAlignment(.leading)`

```
struct Test: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                
            } label: {
                
                    // Your code
                
                    Text("sdfsdlfjskfjsd sdflkjsdf sf sljdflsdkf asfjslkdfj sdfjlskfj sdfjldksfj asdfvfvf fvfvf fvfvl,v vfvl")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                
                    //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be useful to you..

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink {
            Text("fsdf")
        } label: {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("sdfsdlfjskfjsd sdflkjsdf sf sljdflsdkf asfjslkdfj sdfjlskfj sdfjldksfj asdfvfvf fvfvf fvfvl,v vfvl")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.leading) 
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
            .background(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).